# Woocommerce rest api category and image upload/add problem

Tags: php, arrays, rest, post

I can write product form for woocommerce rest api.name,price or description no problem but ,if i add to single category or only add to single image link,responce take to error.Firsty i can share form;

```
<input type ="checkbox" name="test1" id="test1" value="16" /><br>///value is category id
<input type ="checkbox" name="test2"  id="test2" value="17" /><br>///value is category id
```

And php post sciprt;

```
$test1 = $_POST['test1'];
$test2 = $_POST['test2'];
$data = 
[  
'categories' => [
    [
        'id' => $_POST['test1'],
    ],
            [
        'id' => $_POST['test2'],
    ]
],
];
<?php echo json_encode($woocommerce->POST('products', $data)); ?>
```

if i can choose only "test1" or "test2" button ,The following error code appears

```
Notice: Undefined index: test2
Notice: Undefined index: test1
```

I have added a series and tried many times, but I cannot succeed. Can you help me? How can I make a single selection and add a product?

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code you have provided indicates that there are two different checkboxes groups. If you want to make it one. keep the name attribute the same for all.

```
<input type ="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test1" value="16" />
<input type ="checkbox" name="test[]" id="test2" value="17" />
```

when no checkbox is checked, PHP won't receive any POST data named `test`. To check this, you might need to check before you use it.

```php
if(isset($_POST['test'])){
     foreach($_POST['test'] as $report_id){
        echo "$report_id was checked! ";

}
```